# Loop through T model properties. Building a search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm about to build a search page on a website and the search is going to be extensive with a couple of models and with each model having a lot of properties.

Is there a way to do this in a generic way or use reflector as I have seen in some posts? I need some pointers or tips on how to aproach this. Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the information you need. If you have a type T you can use

```
typeof(T).GetProperties()
```

to get all public properties. Same is possible for fields, methods, ... If you need more meta data to generate your search, you can use attributes to annotate the properties (or fields, methods, ...) That's the way I would get started. Further details depend on your exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more details?

What is the purpose of your search?  Give me the 30 second version so I can understand where you are going with this.

Are you planning on using RegEx and word stemming?

What kinds of values count as matches?

I assume you only want to search properties on the objects/models.  Right?

Do want to see every property or only some of them?

What kinds of data is stored in the properties?  (string, byte[], enum, etc)

Brainstorming Ideas:

What about searching one the DB server-side instead of in your hydrated objects?  It might be faster (at run-time) to leverage your DB than load all of the objects into memory then reflect upon them.

You could also write a method that supports your search within the context of the model itself.  You pass in the search rule set as an expression then find the match.  If you have some kind of a collection container, the search could be run at that level against all of the objects in the collection.

If you want some reflection code, I wrote something that shows a lot of info about an object via reflection.  I wrote this a long while ago (Dec 2009).  I'm not sure if it does what you want.  Take a look.  If it works for you, use it! ([Link](http://digitalmoto.net/blog/2009/12/09/examing-an-assembly-through-reflection/))